# Can I pull information using a block of data from an existing resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a terraform code, and i want to use code like this

```
data "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "test" {
  name_prefix = "capture-ec2-scaling-events"
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.console]
}
```

but i getting error " Invalid data source"

What can i do?

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

Since `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` **does not exist** (check TF [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_rule) for list of valid data sources), you can create your own data source instead using [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). This way you can fill out any missing data source that TF lacks.